# Trying to Broadcast an iBeacon using React Native

Tags: ios, node.js, react-native, ibeacon

I am trying to create a simple app using React Native that broadcasts an iBeacon. I have found a possible third-party module called [react-native-ibeacon-simulator](https://github.com/williamtran29/react-native-ibeacon-simulator) but even a simple test fails. I know this has not been updated for some time however I can't find a better solution...

I saved the `index.ios.js` file as iBeacon.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import ibeacon from './ibeacon'

export default class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const uuid = '04bc1d42-98be-4031-a4a9-50c76cb3e1b9'
        const identifier = 'com.myapp'
        ibeacon.startAdvertisingBeaconWithString(uuid, identifier, 0, 0)
    }
    render() {
        return (<View><Text>iBeacon</Text></View>)
    }
}
```

However I get the following error in the terminal (and on the screen of the connected iPhone 6S running iOS13:

```
Warning: %s: Error boundaries should implement getDerivedStateFromError(). In that method, return a state update to display an error message or fallback UI., RootErrorBoundary
- node_modules/expo/build/environment/muteWarnings.fx.js:27:24 in error
- ... 28 more stack frames from framework internals

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'NativeBeaconBroadcast.startSharedAdvertisingBeaconWithString')
* ibeacon.js:19:26 in startAdvertisingBeaconWithString
* App.js:12:43 in componentWillMount
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7430:4 in callComponentWillMount
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/oss/ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7576:27 in mountClassInstance
- ... 19 more stack frames from framework internals
```

I've tried debugging but can't figure out why this is happening...

Comment: I'm having the same issue... any luck?

Answer (score 0):

This probably doesn't help you, but if you check the package's list of known devices that work, iOS is not listed there at all. I think it's incredibly annoying that the package supports a ton of devices I've never heard of but can't support super popular Apple products.

**Phones and tablets**

- Google Pixel [XL], Pixel C, Nexus 6P, 6, 5X, 9, patched Nexus 5
- Alcatel One Touch Idol 3 [Dual SIM], Fierce XL
- Asus Zenfone 2 [Laser], Zenpad 8
- Blackberry Priv
- HTC 10, One M9, Desire (530/626s/820)
- Huawei Ascend Y550, Honor 5X, Union
- Lenovo K3 Note, Vibe P1m, Vibe K4 Note
- LG: G5, G4 [Stylus], G3, G Flex2, G Vista 2, V10, K10, L Bello, Lancet, Leon, Magna, Optimus Zone 3, Spirit, Tribute 5
- Moto X Play, X Style, X2, G2, G3, G4, Z Droid, Droid Turbo 2
- Nextbit Robin
- OnePlus 2, 3
- OPPO A33f
- Samsung Galaxy: S7 [Edge] - up to 8 concurrent running BLE advertisers, S6 [Active/Edge/Edge Plus], S5 [Active/Neo], Note 5, Note Edge, Note 4, Tab S2 (8.0/9.7), Tab S (8.4/10.5), Note Pro, Tab A 9.7, Tab E, A5 2016 [Duos], J5, J3 Duos, Alpha, Core Prime, Grand Prime, On7
- Sony Xperia E5, X, Z5 [Compact/Premium], C5 Ultra, C3, M4 Aqua [Dual]
- Xiaomi Redmi 3, Note 2, Note 3, Mi 4, Mi 4i, Mi 5, Mi Max
- ZTE Maven, ZMAX 2, Zmax Pro, Warp Elite

**Android TVs**

- Sony Bravia 2015